# Ranking highest scoring sample across different assays

Tags: dataset, ranking

So I have a set of data that is composed from 7 samples tested across different assays. In each assay there is an order of data from the highest scoring sample to the lowest scoring one.

I would like to statistically determinate the overall best (highest scoring) sample based on the results from all the assays, then the second one, third one etc. The final order should be visualized.

Is there any kind of statistical method and visualization that could be used here or should I just assign the number for each sample position in every assay (from 1 - 7, 7 meaning the highest scoring sample and 1 the lowest) then sum all the values for each sample and then visualize on bar graph? In that way the sample which showed the best results in all the assays would have the biggest value.

Comment: Just to mention - each assay used describe the amount of one chemical present in the sample- so the highest concentration of the chemical detected in one assay describes the best sample.

Comment: The way you describe it, assuming the top 2 samples are sample1 and sample2 then if  Assay1-Sample1 has a reading of 100/Assay1-Sample2 has a reading of 95 is identical to Assay2-Sample1 has a reading of 100/ Assay2-Sample2 has a reading of 20.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in use (more than in development), you should give a try to [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system.

Rankade is free and easy to use, and it's different from Bradley-Terry model and Elo ranking system (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison)) because it can manage *matches* with 2+ factions (i.e. samples, in your scenario). Inserting assays' ordered rankings (as *matches* between seven samples, with detailed final standings, including ties, if any) you'll obtain the *single ordered ranking of all the samples* you're looking for.
In addiction, rankade give you the opportunity to check time evolution for samples ranking, and stats for samples match-ups, and more.